# My SQL JOIN query returning No results

Tags: mysql, join

```
SELECT 'nmc_cd.CDID','nmc_cd.CDTitle', 'nmc_cd.CDYear','nmc_cd.pubID','nmc_cd.catID','nmc_cd.CDPrice','nmc_category.catDesc'
From nmc_cd
JOIN nmc_category
ON 'nmc_cd.catID'='nmc_category.catID'
ORDER BY CDTitle
```

Ive been putting this query into mySQL to try and get a table with results from ncm_CD and nmc_category but it keeps retuning no value?? also if i use a right or left join it is returning the Column name (e.g. nmc_cd.CDJD)

Comment: if it is returning no rows - then you need to make sure the data actually matches as specified in the where clause. if you get an error, then you should post it, but it looks ok from a quick scan.

Answer (score 3):

Try removing the quotes so that you are referencing the column itself - with quotes, you are working with strings and not the columns.

```
SELECT nmc_cd.CDID, nmc_cd.CDTitle,  nmc_cd.CDYear, nmc_cd.pubID, nmc_cd.catID, nmc_cd.CDPrice, nmc_category.catDesc
From nmc_cd
JOIN nmc_category
ON nmc_cd.catID = nmc_category.catID
ORDER BY CDTitle
```

Also, as @Randy mentions, make sure you actually have data that matches the criteria :)

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure why you have single quotes around everything, a single quote is considered a static string value so it will not return the data from the columns:

```
SELECT nmc_cd.CDID,
    nmc_cd.CDTitle, 
    nmc_cd.CDYear,
    nmc_cd.pubID,
    nmc_cd.catID,
    nmc_cd.CDPrice,
    nmc_category.catDesc
From nmc_cd
INNER JOIN nmc_category
    ON nmc_cd.catID=nmc_category.catID
ORDER BY CDTitle
```

But with the `INNER JOIN` that you are using you have to be sure that you have values that match data in both tables, if you do not then no data will be returned.  If you don't have data in both tables, then you will want to use either a `LEFT JOIN` or `RIGHT JOIN`:

```
SELECT nmc_cd.CDID,
    nmc_cd.CDTitle, 
    nmc_cd.CDYear,
    nmc_cd.pubID,
    nmc_cd.catID,
    nmc_cd.CDPrice,
    nmc_category.catDesc
From nmc_cd
LEFT JOIN nmc_category
    ON nmc_cd.catID=nmc_category.catID
ORDER BY CDTitle
```

MySQL uses backticks around columns and table names not single quotes, if you applied them then your query would look like this:

```
SELECT `nmc_cd`.`CDID`,
    `nmc_cd`.`CDTitle`, 
    `nmc_cd`.`CDYear`,
    `nmc_cd`.`pubID`,
    `nmc_cd`.`catID`,
    `nmc_cd`.`CDPrice`,
    `nmc_category`.`catDesc`
From `nmc_cd`
JOIN `nmc_category`
    ON `nmc_cd`.`catID`=`nmc_category`.`catID`
ORDER BY `CDTitle`
```

Comment: yeh, thats sorted it....single quotes was my mistake, was meant to use the back ticks, cheers though guys!

Comment: @BenArmstrong if any of the answers are helpful to you, please sure to accept the answer via the check mark to the left of it. It helps future visitors to the site.